# two fieldset near each other

Tags: php, html, css

I Need to set the fieldset near each other ...

this the code , plzzzz help i need it to my project ....

how can i do it ?!!

**and one more thing how can i set any input text to maxlength?!**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Main Page</title>
  <meta charset="windows-1256">

  <body bgcolor="black" text="white" alink="aqua" vlink="aqua" link="aqua">
    <center>
      <b>Welcome <!-- put here the username-->&nbsp;You are<!-- Type-->&nbsp;So this all you can see and do ! :)</b><br>
      <fieldset style="width:70%">
        <!-- put here the any thing-->
        <br><br>
        <legend> Subjects Program | C# </legend>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset style="width:20%">
        <!--admin controls-->
        <form action="" method="" name="delete">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="del"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="" size="10%" style="text-align:center" placeholder="Put Username" required>
          <hr>
        </form>
        <legend>Admin Controll</legend>
      </fieldset>
    </center>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Everybody needs help. There is no reason to put that in your title

Comment: @FrankB Yeah sorry about that ....
you know i'm new here :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changes:

- `Wrap your fieldsets in a container` and give it the `display:flex` property as demonstrated.
- Add the attribute of `maxlength="value"` in your input. For example: In this code we have set it to the value of 20, so you can't exceed 20 characters in the username field.

```css
.f-container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Main Page</title>
  <meta charset="windows-1256">
</head>

<body bgcolor="black" text="white" alink="aqua" vlink="aqua" link="aqua">
  <center>
    <b>Welcome <!-- put here the username-->&nbsp;You are<!-- Type-->&nbsp;So this all you can see and do ! :)</b><br>
    <div class="f-container">
      <fieldset style="width:70%">
        <!-- put here the any thing-->
        <br><br>
        <legend> Subjects Program | C# </legend>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset style="width:30%">
        <!--admin controls-->
        <form action="" method="" name="delete">
          <input type="submit" name="" value="del"> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input type="text" name="username" style="text-align:center;width:100%;" placeholder="Put Username" maxlength="20" required>
          <hr>
        </form>
        <legend>Admin Controll</legend>
      </fieldset>
    </div>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Lubbock No problem :)